# Define the return type of a function based on argument

Tags: typescript

I want to define a method in class that will have type based on argument supplied on constructor such as:

```
class A {
    private model: any;
    constructor(model: any) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    getModel() {
        return this.model;
    }
}

class B {
    hello() {
        console.log("hi");
    }
}

class C {
    hi() {
        console.log("hi");
    }
}

const objA = new A(new B());

const objb = objA.getModel();

objb.hello();
```

Here the type of `objb` is `any`, which is the type of `model` in class A, but I want it to be the type of class `B` or any class object I pass into the A class constructor. How can I achieve this in TypeScript?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html

Comment: hi jonrshape. thank you for the link. however, i try to implement zookeeper and beekeeper example but i am getting type `any` only. can you please suggest better approach to get this done

Comment: Please give a [mre] showing how you've tried to apply that to your context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Typescript generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)

```js
class A<Model> {
    private model: Model;
    constructor(model: Model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    getModel(): Model {
        return this.model;
    }
}

class B {
    hello() {
        console.log("hi");
    }
}

class C {
    hi() {
        console.log("hi");
    }
}

const objA = new A(new B());

const objb = objA.getModel();

objb.hello();
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCA8BZA9gEwKYgHzQN4ChojoAHAJwEsA3MAF3WgFs1MAuaFDEAbkOOGQA7CLTIBXYLWRkAFMy7tOmAJR4+xYrQAWFCADp5maAF4mLHuugBffJYDm6WkpAzli82o0ayjsWUHQ2roG5rwaNjb4oJAwAEKexFqYIMiuCV7QAsLIIOh6KXYyAEQ6RcphxBG20VDQAMLp0DppBBlEWRA5eQXFpeWWVVFCItDIAEYAVrAm0ILoAO5wMnOLsa79Q8K0o5NjM+NTeg5O5q68+AdjekkgKWdAA)